# MS SQL 2008 - update record with a value if the grouped total meets a condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out how to update record with a value only in case that the grouped total of a particular type of transactions type is over zero.
In other words, I group my transactions by payment type. If the grouped payment type total is greater than zero, I would like to update each of the transaction in the group with a value.
I cannot figure out that correct statement. Could anyone help please?

```
UPDATE
    T
SET
    T.col1 = OT.col1,
    T.col2 = OT.col2
FROM
    Some_Table T
INNER JOIN
    Other_Table OT ON T.id = OT.id
WHERE
    T.col3 = 'xyz'
-- GROUP BY T.col1
-- HAVING SUM(amount) > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` together with a `SUM() OVER()`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT T.col1 AS tcol1, OT.col1 AS otcol1, T.col2 AS tcol2, OT.col2 AS otcol2,
          SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY T.col1) AS sumAmount
   FROM Some_Table T
   INNER JOIN Other_Table OT ON T.id = OT.id
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET
    tcol1 = otcol1,
    tcol2 = otcol2
WHERE sumAmount > 0
```

The above query will update every row of `Some_Table` that belongs to a `col1` partition with `SUM(amount) > 0`.